# How send push notification for one user using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, cordova

my question is to send push notification to a user in my app using PhoneGap. 
I'm looking on the web but found nothing related to my question. I found ways to send to all users but do not need it.

somebody can help?

Thanks!!!

Comment: are you using any push service? or did you write one in php e.g.?

Comment: I'm currently not using any services.As I said I would send a notification only for 1 user, I had seen the Google service that sends notification for all devices but this is not useful for me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html looking at docs says that you need to specify direct receiver or array in your push request, so not sure whats the problem.